# OpenStack Neutron Plugin for OpenContrail

Tags: apt, package-management, 16.04, openstack, cloud

I am interested to implement OpenContrail within Ubuntu OpenStack.

In Ubuntu 15.10 (Wily) a package is provided:
Package name: neutron-plugin-opencontrail (2:7.0.0-0ubuntu1),
updated in Wily with neutron-plugin-opencontrail (2:7.0.4-0ubuntu1)

I am not able to find such a package for Ubuntu Releases as 14.04.03 (Trusty) or 16.04 (Xenial).

Question: Is OpenContrail plugin for OpenStack Neutron just supported in 15.10? .. or can we use this package from Wily Release also in the 16.04 Release or 14.04.03?

May be in the other releases e.g. 16.04 where I am not able find this OpenContrail Plugin, the driver is already available as OpenStack Neutron ML2 plugin as mechanism driver?

I am interested to make OpenContrail running in an Ubuntu LTS Release (prefered 16.04 or 14.0.4.3) and I wonder that OpenContrail plugin is not available here but listed in 15.10.

Greetings and thanks a lot for support
Thomas

Answer (score 0):

I used this [PPA from tcpcloud](https://launchpad.net/~tcpcloud/+archive/ubuntu/contrail-2.20) to install OpenContrail 2.20 on `Ubuntu 12.04` and `Ubuntu 14.04`. 

`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:tcpcloud/contrail-2.20
sudo apt-get update`

It need some manual resolution of library dependencies but worked out in the end.

May be you can try some [other tcp cloud packages](https://launchpad.net/~tcpcloud) of Open Contrail.